# How to get Facebook Places (check in) on Django web page?

Tags: python, django, facebook

I want to know where I can learn how to integrate Facebook Places on my website.

I want to provide users the capability of selecting nearby places and it'd be very useful if I could use Facebook Places to make this process easier for the audience.

I am not very experienced on programming, so Please don't assume so much from me. Any tips are very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking the official Graph API docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

There is a blog post about places(check in) here which should point you in the right direction:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/403

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will take a look at these links and will keep this thread updated.

Comment: You might also want to check out [django-facebook](http://django-facebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).